# 3d Model with GPS. Android Samples

Tags: sdk, android-gps, kudan, location-based-service, android-augmented-reality

I want to use markerless location-based (GPS+sensors) tracking in order to have a correct registration, by superimposing 3D objects on the real scene.

Are there any Android samples demo for kudan sdk about 3D model with GPS as the one provided for iOS? Can you suggest other similar examples for other sdk?